# Does Cache empty itself if idle for a long time?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Does cache memory refresh itself if doesn't encounter any instruction for a threshold amount of time?

What I mean is that suppose, I have a multi-core machine and I have isolated core on it. Now, for one of the cores, there was no activity for say a few seconds. In this case, will the last instructions from the instruction cache be flushed after a certain amount of time has passed?

I understand this can be architecture dependent but I am looking for general pointers on the concept.

Comment: Yes, deep sleep states can and do power down caches, saving even more power but losing their contents.  [Branch Predictor Entries Invalidation upon program finishes?](//stackoverflow.com/a/59470308) shows this for the BTB on an Intel Broadwell CPU, but I think it's also true for L1i/d caches and maybe also L2 cache.  (L3 cache is separate from individual cores.)

Comment: I do remember reading papers about powering down caches (not just caches just cacheline power gating) in grad school. See Drowsy Caches on Google etc. Not sure if caches are indeed power gated in modern microprocessors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a cache is power-gated in a particular idle state and if it's implemented using a volatile memory technology (such as SRAM), the cache will lose its contents. In this case, to maintain the architectural state, all dirty lines must be written to some memory structure that will retain its state (such as the next level of the memory hierarchy). Most processors support power-gating idle states. For example, on Intel processors, in the core C6 and deeper states, the core is fully power-gated including all private caches. When the core wakes up from any of these states, the caches will be cold.

It can be useful in an idle state, for the purpose of saving power, to flush a cache but not power-gate it. The ACPI specification defines such a state, called C3, in Section 8.1.4 (of version 6.3):

> While in the C3 state, the processor’s caches maintain state but the
>   processor is not required to snoop bus master or multiprocessor CPU
>   accesses to memory.

Later in the same section it elaborates that C3 doesn't require preserving the state of caches, but also doesn't require flushing it. Essentially, a core in ACPI C3 doesn't guarantee cache coherence. In an implementation of ACPI C3, either the system software would be required to manually flush the cache before having a core enter C3 or the hardware would employ some mechanism to ensure coherence (flushing is not the only way). This idle state can potentially save more power compared to a shallower states by not having to engage in cache coherence.

To the best of my knowledge, the only processors that implement a non-power-gating version of ACPI C3 are those from Intel, starting with the Pentium II. All existing Intel x86 processors can be categorized according to how they implement ACPI C3:

- Intel Core and later and Bonnell and later: The hardware state is called C3. The implementation uses multiple power-reduction mechanisms. The one relevant to the question flushes all the core caches (instruction, data, uop, paging unit), probably by executing a microcode routine on entry to the idle state. That is, all dirty lines are written back to the closest shared level of the memory hierarchy (L2 or L3) and all valid clean lines are invalidated. This is how cache coherency is maintained. The rest of the core state is retained.
- Pentium II, Pentium III, Pentium 4, and Pentium M: The hardware state is called Sleep in these processors. In the Sleep state, the processor is fully clock-gated and doesn't respond to snoops (among other things). On-chip caches are not flushed and the hardware doesn't provide an alternative mechanism that protects the valid lines from becoming incoherent. Therefore, the system software is responsible for ensuring cache coherence. Otherwise, Intel specifies that if a snoop request occurs to a processor that is transitioning into or out of Sleep or already in Sleep, the resulting behavior is unpredictable.
- All others don't support ACPI C3.

Note that clock-gating saves power by:

- Turning off the clock generation logic, which itself consumes power.
- Turning off any logic that does something on each clock cycle.

With clock-gating, dynamic power is reduced to essentially zero. But static power is still consumed to maintain state in the volatile memory structures.

Many processors include at least one level of on-chip cache that is shared between multiple cores. The processor branded Core Solo and Core Duo (whether based on the Enhanced Pentium M or Core microarchitectures) introduced an idle state that implements ACPI C3 at the package-level where the shared cache may be gradually power-gate and restore (Intel's package-level states correspond to system-level states in the ACPI specification). This hardware state is called PC7, Enhanced Deeper Sleep State, Deep C4, or other names depending on the processor. The shared cache is much larger compared to the private caches, and so it would take much more time to fully flush. This can reduce the effectiveness of PC7. Therefore, it's flushed gradually (the last core of the package that enters CC7 performs this operation). In addition, when the package exits PC7, the shared cache is enabled gradually as well, which may reduce the cost of entering PC7 next time. This is the basic idea, but the details depend on the processor. In PC7, significant portions of the package are power-gated.

Comment: Great answer. I'm contemplating writing my Bachelor's thesis on caching in Intel CPUs (or something along those lines). Would you happen to be able to share links to literature (books, articles, official documentation etc.) on the topic?

Comment: Your answer on [Branch Predictor Entries Invalidation upon program finishes?](//stackoverflow.com/a/59470308) shows that C3 preserves the BHT / BTB branch-prediction SRAM.  But I guess in an SMP system you can't maintain memory-cache (of physical address space) state without participating in snooping because even clean Shared lines might be invalidated by other cores.  Still, invalidating every line seems pretty expensive.  I guess the difference from fully power-gating caches is faster recovery, just turn the clock back on instead of waiting for voltages to settle, so C3 vs. C7 is meaningful.

Comment: Note that TLB and internal page-walk caches *aren't* coherent so wouldn't have to be flushed.  Presumably the cache-flush microcode uses the same functionality that WBINV does, but skipping L3.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's possible to maintain cache state without participating in snooping. For example, the system can protect all valid lines in the idle core from being accessed from any other agent in a way that breaks coherency. The idle core can then be woken up when such accesses occur. Intel's C3 has chosen the approach where all caches are flushed. Right, paging caches are not hardware-coherent, but they are supposed to be software-coherent. Flushing the paging caches can be avoided if the system can keep a list of all the entries that need to be flushed when exiting the idle state.

Comment: Intel's C3 simply flushes these caches as well. Flushing all of these caches considerably increases the latency to enter and exist from the state, but you can get more power savings (if used intelligently) compared to shallower states. With power-gating, it'd be sufficient to just writeback all dirty lines in the private caches, but you still need to save all architectural state held in registers outside of the core to be power-gated. You'll also lose miroarchitectural state such as branch prediction state. There is also the overhead you mentioned of cutting power and then enabling...

Comment: ...it on wakeup. These overheads are overall larger than that of C3 (flushing the caches and clock-gating the core). It can be practically difficult for the OS to know when to use C3, that's Intel has implemented techniques in the hardware for automatic promotion or demotion of power states chosen by the OS. Usually, you'd want these techniques to be enabled.

Comment: software-coherent paging caches?  Are you talking about Intel's protection against speculative TLB prefetch for "unused" entries http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2015/08/pagewalk-coherence/?  I think that's only within a single core, because of course TLB / page tables are per-core private in the first place.  If another core modifies physical memory that this core's CR3 points to directly or indirectly, an invlpg needs to run on this core, whether it was asleep or not.  Nothing "bad" can happen if the actor we're worried about (this core) is asleep.  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @PeterCordes "an invlpg needs to run on this core, whether it was asleep or not." Right, but if the core is asleep, how are you gonna execute invlpg on it? You either have to flush the paging caches before the core goes to sleep or after. Software-coherent paging caches means that the OS has to maintain coherency of these caches between different cores. Your earlier statement "that TLB and internal page-walk caches aren't coherent so wouldn't have to be flushed" should say that they are not hardware-coherent, but they still have to be coherent. One way to do this is to flush them.

Comment: *Right, but if the core is asleep, how are you gonna execute invlpg on it?* The normal way (e.g. an IPI which wakes it up?).  Putting a core to sleep is orthogonal to the OS software mechanisms for `mmap` / `munmap` in one thread to make sure all other threads that might be running on other cores keep in sync. (mmap to map new virtual address space doesn't need to do this; x86 guarantees no negative caching: just updating a previously invalid PDE or PTE is safe). But munmap and mprotect do have to change possibly-cached mappings, so we wait to hear back or other threads might see stale.

Comment: As [Behavior of mprotect with multiple threads](//stackoverflow.com/q/43722456) points out, presumably an `mprotect` system call can't return until all other cores running threads of the same process have been pinged, whatever the mechanism is.  (Otherwise a synchronizes-with between the syscall thread and another thread wouldn't be sufficient to guarantee safety.  So the high-performance option of sending out requests by not waiting isn't a usable option.)  There aren't remote-invalidate instructions that could get ignored if a core is asleep, are there?

Comment: @PeterCordes Right, but you don't want to interrupt a core in C3 just to flush a TLB entry only to put it back to sleep. This would make C3 less useful. That's why coherency should be maintained before going to sleep or after waking up. (Now I realize this was probably not clear from my earlier comments.) You only want a core to exit from C3 when there is real work to be done and other active cores are already too busy and there are no other cores in shallower states in the same package.

Comment: Ah, I see your point now.  I was just starting to realize that while writing on last comment.  (I found found https://taesoo.kim/pubs/2018/kumar:latr.pdf which confirms the TLB shootdown mechanism of current OSes as being based on sending an IPI).  It would also make `mprotect` slower if it had to wait for another core to wake up.  But yeah, you don't want to have to send IPIs at all to sleeping cores, so yeah you'd need some kind of queue of invalidations.  Or just rewrite CR3 after waking up for safety, at which point you might as well have just invalidate the TLB as part of going to sleep.

Comment: @PeterCordes Another issue with sending an IPI to flush a TLB entry is that in the Sleep state in older processors (see the answer), the processor doesn't even recognize interrupts, so it doesn't work on these processors.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "idle" - specifically whether being "idle" involves the cache being powered or not.

Caches usually consist of registers comprising cells of [SRAM](https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/), which preserve the data stored in them as long as the cells are powered (in contrast to DRAM, which needs to be periodically refreshed). Peter alluded to this in his comment: if power is cut off, not even an SRAM cell can maintain its state and data is lost.

Comment: By "idle", I mean that it might be waiting for user input or something similar so that it doesnt have any instructions to execute. Since I have isolated the core, OS activities can be performed by other cores and this core doesnt need to be disturbed. So, in my use case, cache would have what it had, right?

Comment: @gundechaHills To the best of my knowledge, yes.

Comment: @gundechaHills: no, if this core doesn't do anything for some milliseconds (because the machine is idle and/or this core is isolated with Linux `isolcpus=` and you're not running anything on it), the OS will probably put it into a deep sleep (powered down, losing cache) unless you specifically tell the OS *not* to use deep power-saving states.

Comment: @gundechaHills Sorry, I missed the bit about core isolation. I definitely need to study the matter in more detail in any case; my answer was coming mostly from a place of understanding the basics of SRAM and should not viewed as complete.

Comment: @ihonen: your answer is fine, the wrong assumption that idle won't involve a deep sleep state is only in your first comment.  (isolated isn't really the key here; idle waiting for input will still usually involve a deep sleep state.)