# Start thread within member function using std::thread & std::bind

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have few queries with respect to below code snapshot.

1) With respect to pthread_create(), assume Thread_1 creates Thread_2. To my understanding Thread_1 can exit without join, but still Thread_2 will keep running. Where as in below example without join() I am not able to run thread and I am seeing exceptions.

2) In few examples I am seeing thread creation without thread object as below. But when I do the same, code is terminated.

```
std::thread(&Task::executeThread, this);

I am compiling with below command.
g++ filename.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread
```

But still it terminate with exception. Is this right way of creating thread or is there any different version of C++ (In my project already they are compiling but not sure about the version).

3) In few examples of my project code, I am seeing below way of creating thread. But I am not able to execute with below example.

```
std::thread( std::bind(&Task::executeThread, this) );
```

Below is my code snapshot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Task
{
    public:
    void executeThread(void)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
           std::cout << " :: " << i << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void startThread(void);
};

void Task::startThread(void)
{
    std::cout << "\nthis: " << this << std::endl;

#if 1
    std::thread th(&Task::executeThread, this);
    th.join(); // Without this join() or while(1) loop, thread will terminate
    //while(1);
#elif 0
    std::thread(&Task::executeThread, this);  // Thread creation without thread object
#else
    std::thread( std::bind(&Task::executeThread, this) );
    while(1);
#endif
}

int main()
{
    Task* taskPtr = new Task();
    std::cout << "\ntaskPtr: " << taskPtr << std::endl;

    taskPtr->startThread();

    delete taskPtr;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks & Regards

Vishnu Beema

Comment: maybe you misunderstood the examples. Can you show a complete example of one of the uses of `std::thread( std::bind(&Task::executeThread, this) );` ? Currently your reference to other code that we cannot see is a bit confusing

Comment: You should almost always join threads. One exception is when you are willing to exit the program whiile other threads are still running, effectively killing them.

Comment: In your case, the "Thread_1" is the main thread.<br/>
All threads is belongs/managed by a process. If main thread exit, the process is terminated. So, that is the reason you are not able to run and see exception.

Answer (score 6):

`std::thread(&Task::executeThread, this);` statement creates and destroys a thread object. The [destructor of `std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) invokes `std::terminate` when the thread wasn't joined or detached (like in your statement).

There is no good reason to use `std::bind` in C++11 because lambdas are better in terms of space and speed.

When building multi-threaded code you need to specify `-pthread` option when both compiling and linking. Linker option `-lpthread` is both inadequate and unnecessary.

Comment: There were use cases for `std::bind` that were not possible with lambda until c++14. I don't see a need in this question though.

Comment: @eerorika I can only think of `std::bind` silently ignoring extra arguments, but would like to find out more.

Comment: Capture by move was the one I'm thinking of.

Comment: @eerorika Oh, yes, you are right, I take C++14 for granted nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

By design, you need to join all the threads you spawned, or detach them. See e.g. [SO question on join/detach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015775/what-is-different-between-join-and-detach-for-multi-threading-in-c)

See also [cppreference, detach](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach)

Note also important caveats [if main() exits while detached threads are still running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744250/what-happens-to-a-detached-thread-when-main-exits)

I also 100% agree with the comment in the other answer about preferring lambdas to bind.

Finally, do not fall for the temptation to do pthread_cancel on a thread in C++. See e.g [pthread_cancel considered harmful](https://skaark.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/pthread_cancel-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 1):

1. In C++ objects have a lifetime. This is a bit different then dealing with handles in C. In C++ if you create an object on the stack in one scope it will be destroyed if you exit that scope. There are some exception to these rule like `std::move`, but as a rule of thumb you own the lifetime of an object.
2. This ties into the same answer as above. When you called `std::thread(&Task::executeThread, this);` you were actually invoking the thread constructor. This is the start of the thread life and the object lifetime. Notice that you created this object on the stack. If you leave the scope `{ .. yourcode .. }` the DTor will be called. Since you have done this before `std::move`, `join` or `detatch` then `std::terminate()` is called which is raising the exception.
3. You can create a thread that way. If you look at the linked documentation for std::thread::thread (constructor) there is an example of an object foo being created the same way. What errors are you receiving?

Relevant Documentation:

a. [std::thread::~thread()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread)

b. [std::thread::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

c. [Lifetime in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#targetText=Lifetime)

I personally would recommend understanding the lifetime of objects in a C++. In short all objects start their lifetime when their constructor is invoked. When they are killed (as in out of scope) their destructor is called. The compiler handles this for you so if you're coming from C its a new concept.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your inputs. I missed thread object as part of thread creation. Because of this though compiling, I am getting exceptions. Below is my updated code. All three scenarios are working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Task
{
    public:
    void executeThread(std::string command)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            std::cout << command << " :: " << i << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void startThread(void);
    std::thread th2;
    std::thread th3;
};

void Task::startThread(void)
{
    std::cout << "\nthis: " << this << std::endl;

    #if 0
        std::thread th1(&Task::executeThread, this, "Thread1");
        th1.join(); // Without join(), thread will terminate
    #elif 0
        th2 = std::thread(&Task::executeThread, this, "Thread2");
        th2.join();
    #else
        th3 = std::thread( std::bind(&Task::executeThread, this, "Thread3") );
        th3.join();
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    Task* taskPtr = new Task();
    std::cout << "\ntaskPtr: " << taskPtr << std::endl;

    taskPtr->startThread();

    delete taskPtr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not solve your problem. All you have introduced here is a memory leak. You're not seeing your issue because now, since the taskPtr is a reference type it will not be destructed at the end of this scope.

Comment: @Freddy: Will not delete taskPtr or exit from main() call Task() destructor.